# ¿Cómo hacer que los arrays dentro de los objetos se conviertan en un solo objeto en un nuevo array? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, array, javascript-objeto

Primero quiero explicar la problemática para entender el contexto, y así, encontrar una solución.

Estoy trabajando con la API de Zoom y la API de Google Drive, necesito descargar las grabaciones y luego subirlas a sus respectivas carpetas en Google Drive para que la red interna tenga acceso a las grabaciones aun después que acaben las reuniones.

Al hacer un llamado a la API de Zoom para obtener un listado con todas las grabaciones me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
"meetings": [
{
    "uuid": "uq2z/oe1R2ifOxoGUZQJnw==",
    "id": 84406958671,
    "account_id": "eC52q3fVSkSsBZK0AaRG7g",
    "host_id": "g3k3it22Slaba9iH01fmDg",
    "topic": "CODIGO DE LA REUNION",
    "type": 2,
    "start_time": "2021-03-27T20:55:41Z",
    "timezone": "America/Santiago",
    "host_email": "correo@institucion.cl",
    "duration": 54,
    "total_size": 310591245,
    "recording_count": 2,
    "share_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/share/UUfPYbazH6hMygzbE8OnKn6Rbt2",
    "recording_files": [
        {
            "id": "55fe31bb-84db-41a1-85b0-1464275f9642",
            "meeting_id": "uq2z/oe1R2ifOxoGUZQJnw==",
            "recording_start": "2021-03-27T20:55:45Z",
            "recording_end": "2021-03-27T21:50:00Z",
            "file_type": "MP4",
            "file_extension": "MP4",
            "file_size": 310590975,
            "play_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/play/mqPHwYVsWOcbS8xe56fmcjw061grjS7SEUGuKYl3veZSONBd8MfJTYefy",
            "download_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/mqPHwYVsWOcbS8xe56fmcjw061grjS7SEUGuKYl3veZSONB",
            "status": "completed",
            "recording_type": "shared_screen_with_speaker_view"
        },
        {
            "id": "5871bf57-0c8e-4b24-9422-fd24210cfc8b",
            "meeting_id": "uq2z/oe1R2ifOxoGUZQJnw==",
            "recording_start": "2021-03-27T20:55:45Z",
            "recording_end": "2021-03-27T21:50:00Z",
            "file_type": "CHAT",
            "file_extension": "TXT",
            "file_size": 270,
            "play_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/play/msqYCwLgYT99mxcpYvIfcR4Bg_4bu7n-0vfChM4c22ANUA8B4VBDRd7aKdu1-j3KjuTMInSwL-eAbnW6.jiNG1iVCqX0R0PaQ",
            "download_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/msqYCwLgYT99mxcpYvIfcR4Bg_4bu7n-0vfChM4c22ANUA8B4VBDRd7aKdu1-j3KjuTMInSwL-eAbnW6.jiNG1iVCqX0R0PaQ",
            "status": "completed",
            "recording_type": "chat_file"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "uuid": "sfSOM9eGT1a89Tw6qXe6KQ==",
    "id": 82845119975,
    "account_id": "eC52q3fVSkSsBZK0AaRG7g",
    "host_id": "3Q2er97gRe6G5L5nAmL2Wg",
    "topic": "CODIGO DE LA REUNION",
    "type": 3,
    "start_time": "2021-03-27T00:20:26Z",
    "timezone": "America/Santiago",
    "host_email": "correo@institucion.cl",
    "duration": 62,
    "total_size": 433510740,
    "recording_count": 2,
    "share_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/share/n5C214kB7kaMQUx5NNUdFCvj_puzBW2X7vKvTO3OafFT",
    "recording_files": [
        {
            "id": "388098e8-1d53-4a5f-9297-8e51bdca1ce7",
            "meeting_id": "sfSOM9eGT1a89Tw6qXe6KQ==",
            "recording_start": "2021-03-27T00:20:27Z",
            "recording_end": "2021-03-27T01:23:06Z",
            "file_type": "MP4",
            "file_extension": "MP4",
            "file_size": 433508775,
            "play_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/play/EsUDDuZ-Nj6PskGaSWiKCkjbGWrVSCjJvZjsOGAVGSidH-Jo8tXCjOyypq7zRQGxO3tSk",
            "download_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/EsUDDuZ-Nj6PskGaSWiKCkjbGWrVSCjJvZjsOGAVGSidH-Jo8tXCjOyypq7zRQG",
            "status": "completed",
            "recording_type": "shared_screen_with_speaker_view"
        },
        {
            "id": "d5de587d-2075-465c-8b16-4fb1af1b7b20",
            "meeting_id": "sfSOM9eGT1a89Tw6qXe6KQ==",
            "recording_start": "2021-03-27T00:20:27Z",
            "recording_end": "2021-03-27T01:23:06Z",
            "file_type": "CHAT",
            "file_extension": "TXT",
            "file_size": 1965,
            "play_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/play/ygRj6h1xy3cgo5EVEHB2CIz1TwIfSqNGn3eVr6p1T6m75S4xBu4oQt2SEyhZapY",
            "download_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/ygRj6h1xy3cgo5EVEHB2CIz1TwIfSqNGn3eVr6p1T6m75S4xBu4oQt2",
            "status": "completed",
            "recording_type": "chat_file"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "uuid": "s1tdCTIbRfuRqy2xopfHmw==",
    "id": 89682694079,
    "account_id": "eC52q3fVSkSsBZK0AaRG7g",
    "host_id": "dbYVr6eiScaOxufevtezSw",
    "topic": "CODIGO DE LA REUNION",
    "type": 3,
    "start_time": "2021-03-27T00:06:09Z",
    "timezone": "America/Santiago",
    "host_email": "correo@institucion.cl",
    "duration": 102,
    "total_size": 831048309,
    "recording_count": 2,
    "share_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/share/CfK2P6LG6AqsT43mZyH3bxzpF0G2qogOPMs77UToY",
    "recording_files": [
        {
            "id": "d1bd0969-0d33-4ff8-972c-470e69397846",
            "meeting_id": "s1tdCTIbRfuRqy2xopfHmw==",
            "recording_start": "2021-03-27T00:06:11Z",
            "recording_end": "2021-03-27T01:49:01Z",
            "file_type": "CHAT",
            "file_extension": "TXT",
            "file_size": 52,
            "play_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/play/1IVmlCI2ALQxaS9Dig_-ymyN9YHeEzZMgVI-n_BNPk- ",
            "download_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/1IVmlCI2ALQxaS9Dig_-ymyN9YHeEzZMgVI-n_BNPk-",
            "status": "completed",
            "recording_type": "chat_file"
        },
        {
            "id": "fa769ed3-95aa-4d48-a6ef-1a4cfaa75251",
            "meeting_id": "s1tdCTIbRfuRqy2xopfHmw==",
            "recording_start": "2021-03-27T00:06:11Z",
            "recording_end": "2021-03-27T01:49:01Z",
            "file_type": "MP4",
            "file_extension": "MP4",
            "file_size": 831048257,
            "play_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/play/Vv5PJLfUS9xEWoFDOW_p3uGcgyhNUlA1uqC5ditC_ccDNTFZNsKD_R1FCsHy84S2a8HS71Z01zop",
            "download_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/Vv5PJLfUS9xEWoFDOW_p3uGcgyhNUlA1uqC5ditC_ccDNTFZNsKD_R1FCsHy8",
            "status": "completed",
            "recording_type": "shared_screen_with_speaker_view"
        }
    ]
},
```

Este array tiene objetos, y dentro de los objetos hay una propiedad llamada `recording_files`, el cual, es un arreglo con más objetos. Lo que necesito es que cada objeto dentro del array `meetings`, sea solo un objeto con las propiedades de la reunion y la del archivo MP4. Que no contenga arrays dentro del mismo como en la propiedad `recording_files`.

Esto es lo que quiero conseguir:

```
"meetings": [
    {
        "uuid": "s1tdCTIbRfuRqy2xopfHmw==",
        "id": 89682694079,
        "account_id": "eC52q3fVSkSsBZK0AaRG7g",
        "host_id": "dbYVr6eiScaOxufevtezSw",
        "topic": "CODIGO DE LA REUNION",
        "type": 3,
        "start_time": "2021-03-27T00:06:09Z",
        "timezone": "America/Santiago",
        "host_email": "correo@institucion.cl",
        "duration": 102,
        "total_size": 831048309,
        "recording_count": 2,
        "share_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/share/CfK2P6LG6AqsT43mZyH3bxzpF0G2qogOPMs77UToY",
        "recording_files": 
            {
                "id": "fa769ed3-95aa-4d48-a6ef-1a4cfaa75251",
                "meeting_id": "s1tdCTIbRfuRqy2xopfHmw==",
                "recording_start": "2021-03-27T00:06:11Z",
                "recording_end": "2021-03-27T01:49:01Z",
                "file_type": "MP4",
                "file_extension": "MP4",
                "file_size": 831048257,
                "play_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/play/Vv5PJLfUS9xEWoFDOW_p3uGcgyhNUlA1uqC5ditC_ccDNTFZNsKD_R1FCsHy84S2a8HS71Z01zop",
                "download_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/Vv5PJLfUS9xEWoFDOW_p3uGcgyhNUlA1uqC5ditC_ccDNTFZNsKD_R1FCsHy8",
                "status": "completed",
                "recording_type": "shared_screen_with_speaker_view"
            }
    }
]
```

O este otro resultado:

```
"meetings": [
    {
        "uuid": "s1tdCTIbRfuRqy2xopfHmw==",
        "id": 89682694079,
        "account_id": "eC52q3fVSkSsBZK0AaRG7g",
        "host_id": "dbYVr6eiScaOxufevtezSw",
        "topic": "CODIGO DE LA REUNION",
        "type": 3,
        "start_time": "2021-03-27T00:06:09Z",
        "timezone": "America/Santiago",
        "host_email": "correo@institucion.cl",
        "duration": 102,
        "total_size": 831048309,
        "recording_count": 2,
        "share_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/share/CfK2P6LG6AqsT43mZyH3bxzpF0G2qogOPMs77UToY",
        "meeting_id": "s1tdCTIbRfuRqy2xopfHmw==",
        "recording_start": "2021-03-27T00:06:11Z",
        "recording_end": "2021-03-27T01:49:01Z",
        "file_type": "MP4",
        "file_extension": "MP4",
        "file_size": 831048257,
        "play_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/play/Vv5PJLfUS9xEWoFDOW_p3uGcgyhNUlA1uqC5ditC_ccDNTFZNsKD_R1FCsHy84S2a8HS71Z01zop",
        "download_url": "https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/Vv5PJLfUS9xEWoFDOW_p3uGcgyhNUlA1uqC5ditC_ccDNTFZNsKD_R1FCsHy8",
        "status": "completed",
        "recording_type": "shared_screen_with_speaker_view"
    }
]
```

Esto porque lo único que necesito del array que está dentro del objeto de la reunion `recording_files` es la información del archivo MP4 o que tenga el valor `"shared_screen_with_speaker_view"` en la propiedad `recording_type`. Lo quiero hacer aplicando programación funcional, con el método `reducer()` de los array en JavaScript. Desconozco si esto es posible, ya que, no soy experto trabajando con objetos, y por esto me complica encontrar la solución.

Por ejemplo, esto lo sé hacer de la siguiente manera con arrays que solo tengan un dato dentro de ellos, no con objetos, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
const numeros = [1,2,3,[4,5],6,7,[8,9]]
const numerosReduce = numeros.reduce((acumulador, elemento) => acumulador.concat(el), [])
//Esto devuelve el siguiente resultado
//[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Mientras lo que hago es recorrer los arreglos mediante ciclos y crear un objeto completamente nuevo y guardarlo en una variable temporal para ir agregándolos uno a uno en nuevo array, pero no es el método que me gusta porque sé que puede hacer con un algoritmo mucho menor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que tenemos esto:

```
let obj = {
   "meetings": [
      { "recording_files": [ objA, objB ] },
      { "recording_files": [ objA, objB ] }
   ]
}
```

Podemos reasignar los valores de la memoria:

```
obj.meetings[0].recording_files = obj.meetings[0].recording_files[0]
obj.meetings[1].recording_files = obj.meetings[1].recording_files[0]
```

Dejandonos con:

```
{
   "meetings": [
      { "recording_files": objA },
      { "recording_files": objA }
   ]
}
```

Así que para un caso general podemos usar un `forEach`. Claro que aún se puede usar `reduce` pero supongo que en términos de eficiencia para el navegador es más cómodo hacer asignaciones que trabajar con crear nuevos objetos por completo en el acumulador, en especial si ya tienes tienes una cantidad muy grande de datos en una variable desde un principio.

> Para motivos de la respuesta omití los valores que no eran necesarios y agregue en el caso en que por alguna razón extraña/rara no hay archivo MP4

```js
let res = {
    "meetings": [
        {
            "id": 84406958671,
            "recording_files": [
                {
                    "id": "55fe31bb-84db-41a1-85b0-1464275f9642",
                    "file_type": "MP4"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5871bf57-0c8e-4b24-9422-fd24210cfc8b",
                    "file_type": "CHAT"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 82845119975,
            "recording_files": [
                {
                    "id": "388098e8-1d53-4a5f-9297-8e51bdca1ce7",
                    "file_type": "MP4"
                },
                {
                    "id": "d5de587d-2075-465c-8b16-4fb1af1b7b20",
                    "file_type": "CHAT"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 89682694079,
            "recording_files": [
                {
                    "id": "d1bd0969-0d33-4ff8-972c-470e69397846",
                    "file_type": "CHAT"
                },
                {
                    "id": "fa769ed3-95aa-4d48-a6ef-1a4cfaa75251",
                    "file_type": "UNKNOWN"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

res.meetings.forEach(meeting => {
    meeting.recording_files = meeting.recording_files.find(file => file.file_type === 'MP4') || {}
});

console.log( res );
```

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta!

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me ayudo mucho y resolvió mi problema

Comment: Vengo a dar nuevamente las gracias por esta respuesta, me ayudo mucho. No me quedo muy claro porque es menos conveniente usar reducer pero me quedo claro como poder filtrar arrays que contienen objetos. En el caso particular de mi problema solo necesito los MP4 file_type, aunque me ayudo saber como asignar un objeto vacio en caso de no encontrar el tipo que busco. Me ayudaste bastante.